# Problema con Internet Explorer en Windows 10

Tags: windows10, internet-explorer

Quería borrar internet explorer en windows 10 y aplique este comando en el CMD

```
FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*11.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart"
```

En teoría funciono, pero cuando intento instalar una versión anterior de Internet Explorer no me lo permite porque me aparece que ya tengo una versión mas actual.

Quiero probar a borrar todos los registros de internet explorer desde regedit, pero temo que al estar tan anclado en windows vaya a afectar al Sistema Operativo.

¿Se os ocurre una solución mejor?

Comment: Si quieres usar una versión anterior para hacer tests, puedes [descargar una máquina virtual gratuita de Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)

Comment: He probado a borrar todos los registros en regedit, y todos los directorios del sistema de internet explorer, pero cuando trato de instalar de nuevo internet explorer me sigue apareciendo que tengo una version superior de internet explorer instalada.